# Multiple-entry Schengen visa for France and Portugal

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, paris, portugal

I applied for a Schengen visa 2 months ago for my trip to Greece earlier this month. I was expecting to get a multiple-entry Schengen visa for 3 months, but they only gave a visa for 9 days for the duration of my trip to Greece.

I am now planning to go on a day trip to Paris in August and a trip to Portugal in October. How do I go about applying for the Schengen visa to ensure I get a multiple-entry visa?

Also, since I am not actually staying in Paris, what kind of documents I'd provide as the proof of accommodation?

Thank you.

Comment: Your citizenship(s) and country of residency might make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do anything to ensure getting a multi-entry visa.

The authorities are free to issue whatever type of visa they feel like, their decision depends on multiple things:

- your travel history (frequency and obeying the terms are good)
- your citizenship
- your country of residence
- (I've probably forgotten something)